# Windows boot manager error Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader

My Thinkpad arrived with Windows 7. I upgraded to Windows 8. Shortly after I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on a separate partition. Shortly after Windows crashed irretrievably (no DVD, no access to anyone with Win 8 to create DVD). So carried on using Ubuntu and upgraded to 14.04

Recently upgraded another laptop from XP to Win 8.1 and decided to resurrect Win 8 on the Thinkpad on its original partition. No probs except now although both O/S are offered in the Windows start panel only Win 8 boots.

This is the error info I get when trying to use Ubuntu:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr    

  Status: 0xc000000f  

  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required  
        file is missing or contains errors.
```

Any suggestions for a reasonably amateur user? Thanks

Comment: Try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

Master Boot Record(MBR) of Windows is corrupted. Try to repair start-up of Windows using Automatic Start-up Repair. You need a Windows DVD to do so. But be careful you may not be able to boot into Ubuntu afterwords.